# How can I remove these options from the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

To prevent inadvertent switching, I want to remove two options from the the dashboard:

1. Membership.(In Settings-General - options-general.php.)
2. Visual editor. (in Users-profile - profile.php.)

I want the default text and check-boxes to be replaced by a message of 'This option has been disabled.

With css I can hide the boxes and add a message, but I'd rather the html was absent.

I've no idea where to begin with this.

Comment: It's possible to remove and add items to your WordPress dashboard, but you will need to update your post for precision; what are you referring to by *Membership* and *Visual editor*? Third parties plugins? Which are of the dashboard? Menu? Main content?

Comment: @nyedidikeke... Updated for clarity, though anyone able to answer is likely to know exactly what's being referred to because they're default functions.

Comment: Visual Editor is an option in Core WP, but Membership isn't

Comment: @Tom J Nowell... maybe my words are wrong... isn't the 'Anyone can register' option a default feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [remove_menu_page function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) from the [admin_menu action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu).

An example for you would be to add this to your functions file (this will remove those menu links for you as well).

```
function remove_menus() {

    remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );
    remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

If you need to be more specific to a user group, or an individual user (or exclude a user) you can use things like [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) or [get_current_user_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) to be more specific.

Comment: @socki03...thanks. That removes the menu items - which isn't what I want. Those pages need to be present, but with each having a specific option removed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread what you needed.  Without editing the core templates, I'm not sure you can remove those specific sections.  And you should really never edit core templates.